# reloadData Crashing iOS App

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsurl

I'm doing a Twitter request for API data with:

```
TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=a2zwedding&include_entities=true"] parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
```

then I'm getting all processing the request with:

```
[postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    // NSString *output;
    NSArray *results;

    if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) {
        NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
        NSDictionary *publicTimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
        results = [publicTimeline objectForKey:@"results"]; 
    }
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(populateTable:) withObject:results waitUntilDone:YES];        
}];
```

I'm then trying to display the "results" in a UITableView. My delegate and datasource are the same view controller that is processing the JSON data. My datasource method of:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

is returning zero if I try to do the count of my array because my JSON parsing isn't finished when this gets called.  If I "return 1" with this method, it properly displays one of the results from my Twitter request.  However, if I use reloadData my app crashes.  I cannot get it to delay the count.  Any ideas?

Comment: How are you creating your table view, and how are you calling reloadData?

Comment: Also, posting the error you get when you crash is helpful.

Comment: Sounds like you're not retaining your data. Seeing your populateTable: implementation would be useful. Also, you need to either initialize the results variable when you declare it, or set it to nil if the statusCode isn't 200.

Answer (score 0):

in .h

```
//use this as your datasource
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSArray *myResultData;
```

.m

```
@synthesize myResultData;

[postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
// NSString *output;
NSArray *results;

if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) {
    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    NSDictionary *publicTimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
    results = [publicTimeline objectForKey:@"results"]; 
    if(![results isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
       {
          myResultData = [NSArray alloc]initWithArray:results];
       }
       [self.tableView reloadData];
}
}];
```